# Error when trying to fill Datatable from Excel file

Tags: .net, excel, datatable, oledb

I am trying to get the data from an excel file into a datatable. My code is below and my error is, "IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)." And this error occurs at the line, "dbAdapter.Fill(dt);"

```
    protected void uploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            if (ctlFileUpload.HasFile)
            {
                string strFileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(ctlFileUpload.FileName).ToString().ToLower();
                if (strFileType == ".xls" || strFileType == ".xlsx")
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    string strConn = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"", ctlFileUpload);

                    using (OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", dbConnection)) //rename sheet if required!
                            dbAdapter.Fill(dt);
                        int rows = dt.Rows.Count;
                    }

                }
                else { throw new Exception("Excel File Only"); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            if (ex.Message == "Incorrect Format")
            {
                lblStatusMessage.Text = "Excel is in an incorrect format, please use the template provided.";

            }
            else if (ex.Message == "Excel File Only")
            {
                lblStatusMessage.Text = "Only Excel files are allowed, please use the template provided.";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatusMessage.Text = ex.Message;
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

The file I am uploading does not have any spaces in it's name and is in the .xlsx format. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A sample of the file's data would be helpful.

Comment: The excel file only has two rows, a header and one row of data. I am not sure what format would help best but here it is comma separated. 


Prod #, Color #, Trim SKU, Price Rule, Add %, Base $, Add Base Surcharge, Start Date, End Date, Active

Row 2 includes. 

935, 200, Quantity Price, $10.00, 1/1/2010, 1/1/2030, Yes

Comment: Have you specified actual file name in 'strConn' variable? You only passed the object of fileupload control.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to save that file before using it in the connection string.
Also the connection string should use the FileName property not the whole FileUpload control

So for example

```
....
if (ctlFileUpload.HasFile)
{
    string strFileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(ctlFileUpload.FileName).ToLower();
    if (strFileType == ".xls" || strFileType == ".xlsx")
    {
        string fileName = "/APP_DATA/" + ctlFileUpload.FileName;
        ctlFileUpload.SaveAs(fileName);

        string strConn = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                         Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;
                         HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"", 
                         fileName);
    .....
```